# Windows phone debugging in device

Tags: debugging, windows-phone-7

I am a windows phone app developer. My PC do not have enough graphics to support windows phone emulator. So I am developing application by using the windows phone device (HTC HD7) for debugging and testing from almost 5 months now. Now my device is so hanging and switch-off automatically sometimes. Is it bad for the device to use the developing purpose rather than using emulator ?. Is my device have problem because of the continuous use for developing ?

Comment: I am using my device from last 1.5 years for development and debugging. Never get such issue. Might be problem in your device. And as per my understanding debugging can not effect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not a problem in using device for the developing purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a fault in the device - I'd send it in for repair. I've certainly not heard of debugging causing issues with devices.

Answer (score 0):

Do check if your internal storage is about getting full. Also if you have minimum RAM config, try not using multiple apps while debugging. Probably this should help.

And nonetheless, you can just visit a technician and get your phone thoroughly checked for issues.